# Compatible with iPhone, iPod touch and

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, app-store

I uploaded an app on app store just for iphone and ipod touch but on app store write

> Compatible with iPhone, iPod touch and
>   iPad

why? is it necessary that i do something in iphone sdk ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry. iPhone (and iPod touch) applications are "automagically" compatible with the iPad. In other words, they can be run unmodified. When executed in an iPad, they are zoomed in order to fill the whole screen.

Answer (score 1):

just leave it as it is. that doesn't mean that your app is universal.
the ipad can run iphone apps.